# Tesla scroll animation

Tags: animation, scroll, tesla

im trying to recreate Tesla website using react and got stuck on Tesla home page animation, where when you scroll down the page, section that is fixed loses and gains opacity and also changes text content based on image that user scrolled to. Sorry for my bad english and explination, but dont know how to explain it better.

Been trying to use framer-motion but sadly it didnt work out. Maybe someone can guide me on how to do it and have any examples?